# How does the Flame malware take advantage of MD5 collision?

Tags: collision-resistance, md5

It's said that [malware Flame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_%28malware%29) used an MD5 collision to get "a counterfeit copy of the certificate".

We know that MD5 is broken on collision attack, but not broken on pre-image attack, thus the only way to get a fake cert is to generate the fake cert when applying for a legitimate cert.

My questions are :

1. Isn't it too dangerous for the virus maker to do this? (We can check who applied for the legitimate cert and catch him.)
2. If he can apply for a legitimate cert, why bother making a couterfeit cert? Why don't use the legitimate cert to sign anything he like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you missed reading a part of that Wikipedia article:

> … Flame was signed with a fraudulent certificate purportedly from the Microsoft Enforced Licensing Intermediate PCA certificate authority.  ***The malware authors identified a Microsoft Terminal Server Licensing Service certificate that inadvertently was enabled for code signing and that still used the weak MD5 hashing algorithm, then produced a counterfeit copy of the certificate that they used to sign some components of the malware to make them appear to have originated from Microsoft.***…

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

In simpler words this means that the malware author(s) didn’t need to apply for a certificate himself/herself/themselves. Instead, the malware author(s) used a genuine Microsoft certificate he/she/they found and created a fake certificate based on that. That way, it seems as if Microsoft itself has signed some files – which Microsoft (of course) didn’t.

So, your …

> thus the only way to get a fake cert is to generate the fake cert when applying for a legitimate cert.

… is partly correct, but it’s only one side of the coin. The other way to get a fake certificate is to find a legitimate but weak and exploitable certificate from someone else – like one from Microsoft in this case.

Having said that, let’s answer your two questions:

> 1. Isn't it too dangerous for the malware author(s) to do this? (We can check who applied for the legitimate cert and catch him)

No, since the fake certificate was based on a Microsoft certificate the malware author(s) got his/her/their hands on. That way, the fake certificate points to Microsoft (just like the genuine certificate it was based on), not the identity of any malware author(s).

> 2. If he can apply for a legitimate cert, why bother making a couterfeit cert? Why don't use the legitimate cert to sign anything he like?

Not being Microsoft, the malware author(s) would hardly have had a chance to apply for a legit Microsoft certificate… and a certificate on his/her/their own name(s) would indeed have been pretty useless for his/her/their intended purposes as that would have added his/her/their name(s) to the equation.

Applying for his/her/their own legitimate certificate would have been a pretty stupid move while having the option to impersonate a trusted company like Microsoft. Remember the fact that the malware author(s) had access to a genuine Microsoft certificate with code signing enabled. (see first quote of my answer)

**All in all you could say the malware author(s) found *"a pot full of gold at the end of some rainbow"* (read: a weak and exploitable Microsoft certificate with code signing enabled) and used what he/she/they found to his/her/their fullest malicious advantage.**

Microsoft dropped a ball, and the malware author(s) picked it up. It was that simple for them. After Microsoft became aware of the situation, they handled the situation accordingly.

Quoting [**"Microsoft releases Security Advisory 2718704"**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/2012/06/03/microsoft-releases-security-advisory-2718704/) dated June 3, 2012:

> We are taking several steps to remove this risk:
>
> - First, today we released a Security Advisory outlining steps our customers can take to **block software signed by these unauthorized certificates**.
> - Second, we released an update that automatically takes this step for our customers.
> - Third, the **Terminal Server Licensing Service no longer issues certificates that allow code to be signed**.
>
> These actions will help ensure that **any malware components that might have been produced by attackers using this method no longer have the ability to appear as if they were produced by Microsoft**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

## But how did they do it?

Quoting [an article from “nakedsecurity” – Sophos‘ blog](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/06/07/microsoft-speaks-out-on-flame-malware-certificate-forgery/):

> …
>
> In the Flame case, the attackers took a legitimate Microsoft certificate using MD5 for its hash and RSA-2048 for its public-key encryption. They then generated a similar-but-different certificate with the same MD5 hash. This means that the RSA-2048 signature from Microsoft’s genuine certificate could be grafted into their forged certificate to make it appear valid.
>
> …

Obviously, the above quote doesn’t really provide any real details.

In fact, explaining all the details would be a bit too broad to post as an answer here, but if you really want to dive deeper into an analysis of the Flame MD5 case, check the PDF: [**“Analyzing the MD5 collision in Flame”**](https://trailofbits.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/flame-md5.pdf). Those 40 pages/slides walk you through details with screenshots etc.

Long story short: **For Flame, a chosen-prefix collision attack against MD5 has been used.** Its malware author(s) used a new variation of a chosen-prefix collision attack to spoof code signing of its components by a Microsoft root certificate that still used the compromised MD5 algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yes I read that emphasized part, but as mentioned, MD5 is broken against collision attack (we can generate $a,b$ satisfying $MD5(a)=MD5(b)$), but isn't broken against (second) pre image attack( Given $a$, it's (nearly) impossible to generate $b$ with $MD5(b)=MD5(a)$), that's why I guess they may applied for a cert as well. If they didn't apply for a cert, that means they launched a successful second pre image attack on MD5, how could that happen?

Comment: @vince.h.c Edited my answer. See "But how did they do it?"

Comment: I have read the 2004 & 2008 paper, all they did is collision attack, not second pre image attack(the 2008 paper has to apply for a legit cert to generate a fake cert). But in order to fake a MS cert, one has to launch a second pre image attack. :(

Comment: @vince.h.c Re `the 2008 paper has to apply for a legit cert to generate a fake cert` – So? Note that the malware author(s) used a new variation of a chosen-prefix collision attack to spoof code signing of its components by **a legit Microsoft root certificate that still used MD5**. In other words: a legit cert was accessibile to them (until Microsoft became aware of the issue and took care of their own glitch). No second pre image attack needed! Check that PDF I linked to at the end of my answer… it’ll provide the needed insights to grasp how the legit MS cert was exploited with an MD5 attack.

Comment: Read the 40 page and got it.  Is this a better way to explain? Everyone can ask MS CA to issue a Terminal LS cert  -> Terminal LS cert cannot be used to sign codes on Vista and Win7 -> The adversary use MD5 collision to generate a cert that's able to sign codes (But he do have to apply for a Terminal LS cert)

Comment: @vince.h.c Yep. Seems you got it.

Comment: @vince.h.c Btw: When the answer fits your needs, please feel encouraged to push the accept button (✔) left of the answer. That way, the system and other users know that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.